# how do i install wine on linux mint maya?

Tags: installation

i'm new to linux. i recently installed linux mint maya {mate} in my home computer and lisa in the office. i need to run some windows programs on my computers. wine installed just fine in the office. however, i cannot install wine in maya for any time i try installing it from the software manager, it takes forever to load. a few other programs do the same. whenever i try using the synaptic, i am informed of broken packages. please help, am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tutorial [here](http://www.thepowerbase.com/2012/04/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu-or-debian/) for fixing broken packages.

You can install wine by running the following commands in Mint.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5 winetricks
```

Link to [Wine Official site](http://www.winehq.org/) and also check out [PlayonLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

Comment: i tried this and this is the result